# Browser top bar does not scroll with content

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When displaying a flutter app from a **browser** (chrome in this example) **on a mobile device**, the browser's app bar does not scroll off screen when the content of the page is scrolled. Is there a way to achieve that scroll?

***This question regards to Flutter Web only***

### Demo

Here is a comparison between a flutter demo app and a simple search results page on Google. You can see how the app bar doesn't move in the first example but does move on the search results page.
[image]

### Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final List<ListTile> _list = List.generate(50, (index) {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text('Hello World $index'),
  );
});

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Material(
        child: ListView(
          children: _list,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```